# Better proposal for the tag "Mathematics in daily life"

Tags: discussion, tags

I've just created the tag [mathematics-in-daily-life](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematics-in-daily-life), but I'm not that happy about the title.

Can anyone suggest a better title for it?

Comment: It depends on what the tag is meant to convey.  Some possible titles might be "[numeracy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeracy)", "[quantitative literacy](http://www.maa.org/programs/faculty-and-departments/curriculum-department-guidelines-recommendations/quantitative-literacy)" and "everyday-applications".

Comment: I asked a question about statistics (e.g. in newspapers). I'm thinking about mathematics which every person (even not a mathematician) can meet in his life outside school and college. **everday-applications** sound also good.

Comment: I like @JimBelk's suggestion of quantitative-literacy.